# Hofstadter equation related code in python

Tags: python, math, sequences

There was this question in a university assignment related to Hofstadter sequence. It basically say that it is a integer sequence blah blah and there are two values for a given index n. A male value [M(n)] and a female value [F(n)].

They are defined as:

- M(0)=0
- F(0)=1
- M(n)=n-F(M(n-1))
- F(n)=n-M(F(n-1))

And we were asked to write a program in python to find the Male and Female values of the sequence of a given integer.

So the code I wrote was:

```
def female(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    elif num >0:
        return num - male(female(num-1))
def male(num):
    if num==0:
        return 0
    elif num >0:
        return num - female(male(num-1))
```

And when executed with a command like 
  `print male(5)`
It works without a fuss. But when I try to find the value of n = 300, the program gives no output. 
So I added a print method inside one of the functions to find out what happens to the num value

[     `elif num>0:
            print num ...`]

And it shows that the num value is decreasing until 1 and keeps hopping between 1 and 2 at times reaching values like 6.

I can’t figure out why it happens. Any insight would be nice. Also what should I do to find the values relevant to bigger integers. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is theoretically fine. What you underestimate is the complexity of the computation. Formula

```
M(n)=n-F(M(n-1))
```

actually means

```
tmp = M(n-1)
M(n) = n - F(tmp)
```

So if you represent this calculation as a tree of necessary calls, you might see that its a binary tree and you should go through all its nodes to calculate the results. Given that `M(n)` and `F(n)` are about `n/2` I'd estimate the total number of the nodes to be of order `2^(n/2)` which becomes a huge number once you put `n = 300` there. So the code works but it just will take a very very long time to finish.

The one way to work this around is to employ caching in a form of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). A code like this:

```
femCache = dict()
def female(num):
      #print("female " + str(num))
      global femCache
      if num in femCache:
        return femCache[num];
      else:
        res = 1 # value for num = 0
        if num > 0:
             res = num - male(female(num-1))
        femCache[num] = res
        return res

maleCache = dict()
def male(num):
      #print("male " + str(num))
      global maleCache
      if num in maleCache:
        return maleCache[num];
      else:
        res = 0 # value for num = 0
        if num > 0:
             res = num - female(male(num-1))
        maleCache[num] = res
        return res

print(male(300))
```

should be able to compute `male(300)` in no time.

Comment: So I tried checking the output with several inputs using this code.   It gives the same sequence in both instances, male and female and that sequence (which is the output of this code) is a wrong sequence.

Comment: @ulama, Sorry the idea was correct but there were some stupid copy/paste errors in the code. Namely 1) `maleCache` was used in `female` instead of `femCache` 2) `female(0)` was `0` instead of `1`. Check updated code.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I figured something was wrong with the cache-ing. But couldn’t figure out which one goes to where. Thanks again.

Comment: @ulama, I think it makes sense for you to find out how this code really works and what's was wrong originally. Memoization is actually a quite useful method so it is good to know how to do it yourself.